# Ajax php database select not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Pls I need help. I have a select code that is not working correctly in ajax.
I actually don't know where I got it wrong but the codes won't work.
Here are the codes:

```
<?php

require_once 'config/dbconfig.php';

if (isset($_REQUEST['note_id'])) {

    $id = intval($_REQUEST['note_id']);
    $query = "SELECT note_id, class, subject, topic, content, author FROM notes WHERE note_id = :id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    ?>


    <div class="card-body">

                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                        <h5 class="text-center"><?php echo $row['class']; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                        <h5 class="text-center"><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                        <h5 class="text-center"><?php echo $row['topic']; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                     <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                        <?php echo $row['content']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                        <h5 class="text-center"></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                        <h5 class="text-center"></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                        Created By: <h5 class="text-center"><?php echo $row['author']; ?></h5>
                    </div>
                     </div>


                    </div>

    <?php               
}
?>
```

Is ajax which is suppose to bring the above select codes to the parent page. But is not working.

Here are the ajax codes:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

        var uid = $(this).data('note_id');   // it will get id of clicked row

        $('#dynamic-content').html(''); // leave it blank before ajax call
        $('#modal-loader').show();      // load ajax loader

        $.ajax({
            url: 'getnotes.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'note_id='+uid,
            dataType: 'html'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);  
            $('#dynamic-content').html('');    
            $('#dynamic-content').html(data); // load response 
            $('#modal-loader').hide();        // hide ajax loader   
        })
        .fail(function(){
            $('#dynamic-content').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Something went wrong, Please try again...');
            $('#modal-loader').hide();
        });

    });

 });

</script>
```

Am calling it via an anchor tag here is the anchor code:
Actually am using a foreach loop.

```
  <li><a data-id="<?php echo $row['note_id']?>" href="#1" class="waves-effect" id="getUser"><?php echo $row['topic']?></a>
                                    </li>
```

When I click on the link it works but it doesn't display the request in the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP, you're adding a data attribute to the anchor. This is `data-id`.

```
<a data-id="<?php echo $row['note_id']?>" ...
```

In your client-side script, you are getting the wrong data attribute. `data-note_id` does not exist. I think you confused the database column name and the data attribute name you gave.

```
var uid = $(this).data('note_id');
```

Should be:

```
var uid = $(this).data('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to get the value of the attribute "data-id".

Here it is.

```
var uid = $(this).attr('data-id');
```